# How to use CCV in Android?

Tags: android, c++, ocr, tesseract

I want to use SWT(Stroke Width Transform) algorithm to improve Tesseract-OCR accuracy. I referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361583/how-to-use-opencvtesseract-for-accurate-text-recognition-in-android).

I found [ccv](http://libccv.org/tutorial/) and a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864043/using-ccv-on-android-device) to use it.

I want to use [ccv_swt](http://libccv.org/lib/ccv-swt/) method, but I don't know how to use exactly.
Especially, `ccv_swt_param_t params` part.

This is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private Mat matInput;
private Mat matGray;
public native void ocrTest(long matAddrGray, long matAddrCanny, long matAddrBlur);
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

 matInput = inputFrame.rgba();
 Imgproc.cvtColor(matInput, matGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
 ocrTest(matGray.getNativeObjAddr(), matCanny.getNativeObjAddr(), matBlur.getNativeObjAddr());

}
```

**native-lib.cpp**

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_ocrtest_MainActivity_ocrTest(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jlong matAddrGray,
                                          jlong matAddrCanny, jlong matAddrBlur) {

// TODO
    Mat &matGray = *(Mat *) matAddrGray;
    Mat &matCanny = *(Mat *) matAddrCanny;
    Mat &matBlur = *(Mat *) matAddrBlur;

    int lowThreshold = 50;
    int highThreshold = 150;

    Canny(matGray, matCanny, lowThreshold, highThreshold, 3);
    blur(matGray, matBlur, Size(3, 3));

}
```